# How can I access environmental variables with WAMP server?

Tags: environment-variables, wamp, getenv

I'm trying to adapt my code to use different database password etc depending on the environment it runs in. For example, I have my dev server, the other developer has his and production env has yet another set of settings.

Since I have some Kohana projects as well, I chose to use the environmental variable KOHANA_ENV for the app to determine where it runs.

The problem is that in my WAMP server, while this works:

```
<?php echo getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); ?>
```

, this doesn't (returns emptyness):

```
<?php echo getenv('KOHANA_ENV'); ?>
```

When I type `set` in the Command Prompt, I see this:

```
KOHANA_ENV=devbox1
```

so it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAMP does not run as the person running wampmanager.exe but rather what the Apache service has been set up to run as. Generally it's LocalService (Local System Account).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821761 states that

> If you update environment variables or add new environment variables,
>   you must restart the computer before the changes that you make affect
>   services that run under the Local System account.
>
> This behavior occurs because services that run under the Local System
>   account inherit their environment from the Services.exe process. The
>   Services.exe process receives the environment settings for the Local
>   System account when Windows starts. Because the Services.exe process
>   does not use Windows Messaging, when it receives messages that
>   indicate that a value has changed after Windows starts, the
>   Services.exe process does not update its environment settings. You
>   cannot force a service that is running to acknowledge a dynamic change
>   to the environment of the Local System account.

And indeed when the computer is restarted after adding the environmental variable to the System environmental variables, this code:

```
<?php echo getenv('YOUR_ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLE'); ?>
```

will print what is expected.

Comment: i tried this `getenv()` and `putenv()` but `putenv()` does not save the variable permanently.    how can I find the physical file on my server where I can save variable manually for permanent use means it do not unset on wamp/os restart. (I have dev win/wamp and server ubunto/xamp) need file for both

Answer (score 0):

this rings a bell.. try this maybe,

```
global $HTTP_ENV_VARS;
echo $HTTP_ENV_VARS["KOHANA_ENV"]
```

Comment: Nope. This, too, returns nothingness.